# GCP - Loadbalancer pricing when using nginx ingress controller

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

How to calculate the pricing for GCP loadbalancers when using nginx ingress controller?

Right now I have 1 Ingress host and a single rule for prod website. But I want to launch another for internal services both gitlab, jenkins.

Is the cost calculated based on the number of `path's` we have in ingress? Or number of load balancers like AWS? I'm assuming each `rule` in GCP calculator means a `path` in ingress.

Comment: Are you using GKE?

Comment: yes I'm using GKE

Comment: No, for GCP, a "forwarding rule" is almost always one-to-one with a public IP address. It's something different than your `path`.  Your `path` is for GCP the "url map", which is free (not billable).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NGINX Ingress Controller like [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke), then your are only billed for your GKE cluster.
Please have a look at [GKE pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing):

> GKE uses Compute Engine instances for worker nodes in the cluster. You
> are billed for each of those instances according to Compute Engine's
> pricing, until the nodes are deleted. Compute Engine resources are
> billed on a per-second basis with a one-minute minimum usage cost.

In addition, be aware of networking pricing, more information can be found in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing).

You can also estimate the cost yourself with this [Google Products Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

Comment: @John Does this answer your question?